# Skrollr JS - Pausing certain elements to do other scroll animation

Tags: javascript, skrollr

I'm currently working on my portfolio site. My site is heavily dependant on scroll animation and I'm using skrollr js to do just that.
What I currently have is this [demo](http://sujan-tpc.github.io/) and this was a result of tweaking the zombie parallax tutorial version on Dev.Opera. This [polished version of zombie parallax](http://www.cabletv.com/the-walking-dead) has what I'm looking for, the pause at different sections of the animation.

In my project, I want to pause the character when I come close to the flag and the landmarks and I want those elements to rise up from the ground and then a short description of text will fade in (or whatever im not sure yet) and then after a while the character needs to keep moving and those landmarks need to move away from the viewport to the left so it seems like the character is travelling.

I checked out the pausing example on the skrollr github page but I couldn't wrap my head around it so I'd be really thankful if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not a skrollr expert bt tyr this @sujan:

```
<div id="scene" class="gradient">
    <div id="ground" class="parallax-layer" data-0="left:0px;" data-3300="left:-500px;" data-4500="left:-500px;"  data-5000="left:-1500px;"></div>
    <div class="parallax-layer">
        <div id="swayambhu" class="birthplace" data-0="left:2100px;" data-3300="left:700px;" data-4500="left:700px;" data-5500="left:-400px;"></div>
        <div id="dharahara" class="birthplace" data-0="left:2000px;" data-3300="left:600px;" data-4500="left:600px;" data-5300="left:-300px;"></div>
        <div id="nepal-flag" class="birthplace" data-0="left:1800px;"data-3300="left:400px;" data-4500="left:400px;" data-5000="left:-300px;"></div>
        <div id="character"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="sujan-title" data-0="left:0px;" data-3500="left:-3000px;"></div>
    <div id="start" data-0="left:0px;" data-3500="left:-2000px;">Scroll down or press "DOWN" key to move</div>
</div>
```

and call skrollr on variable:

```
var animate = skrollr.init({});
```

that way you can use scrollr animation functions like :

```
animate.getScrollTop() etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. With a little bit of extra data-attributes and tweaking with the js files I managed to get what I wanted.
[Check here](http://sujan-tpc.github.io/)